# Data Validation for Random varying Phone Numbers

Tags: c#, string, validation, int, tryparse

I am storing phone numbers of varying lengths in my WPF (C#, VS 08) App.

I store them as strings. My question is about my method `AddNewPhoneNo(string phoneNo)`.

In this method, I use `Int.TryParse` to validate the incoming number (i.e. not null, is numeric...). I've since realized this is probably not the best way to do this, because then I am limited to a number which is ± 2147483647. Definetly this is not always the case with phone numbers.

What is a good, easy way to validate phone numbers? I guess the basic rules would be as follows:

- All numeric
- All positive
- Upto 25 chars (could be more, but this will to do for time being)

Can't thing if theres any more rules at the moment, that's probably it.

Comment: why on earth are you using Int.TryParse on a phone number? A regular expression might be a better choice.

Comment: `Int.TryParse` on phone number was to ensure it was numeric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your constraints are that the string must be not-null, nothing but numbers, and <= 25 chars, then you can simply do the following:

```
static bool IsValidPhoneNumber(string phoneNumber)
{
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(phoneNumber)
        && (phoneNumber.Length <= 25)
        && phoneNumber.All(c => char.IsNumber(c));
}
```

If your constraints are more complex (e.g. the string can contain digit grouping like "123-456-7890" or parenthesis like "(123)4567890") then you should go with RegEx.

Answer (score 1):

How about a RegEx pattern: [http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=45](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=458)8

Comment: I guess so, I had been told to avoid these but guess it may be simplest and easiest method

Comment: @baron - RegEx can be confusing and hard to debug but I think for this type of well known pattern (and already existent RegEx) it's pretty safe to say it's probably the best method.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `Int64.TryParse` which would give you a range of ±9223372036854775807